# which function is called when screen is returned from other screen in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I can see the React native component life cycle. componentDidMount, UNSAFE_componentWillMount, etc
I thought UNSAFE_componentWillMount is called when screen is resumed. But it is not called.
I use React 17 over, React Native 0.68.1, and I use navigation.goBack() to return from second screen to first screen.
Which function is called when screen is resumed? Or what other way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to be careful here. In `react-native` a screen `remains mounted on navigation`. This [differs from the web](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle).

> If you are coming to react-navigation from a web background, you may assume that when user navigates from route A to route B, A will unmount (its componentWillUnmount is called) and A will mount again when user comes back to it. While these React lifecycle methods are still valid and are used in react-navigation, their usage differs from the web.

Hence, if you navigate via `goBack`, the `componentWillMount` will not be called again, since the screen `remains mounted`. There is a general workaround for this problem [which is documented here in the React Navigation lifecycle events section](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle).

For `functional components`, we can use the `useFocusEffect` hook as follows.

```js
useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      // Do something when the screen is focused

      return () => {
        // Do something when the screen is unfocused
        // Useful for cleanup functions
      };
    }, [])
  );
```

For `class components`, we can use a `focus listener`. This is [documented here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/).

```js
class SomeClassComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this._unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      // do whatever
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._unsubscribe();
  }

...
```

In some cases it might be more convenient to still use functional components. We can simply wrap a legacy class component into a functional component as follows.

```js
const Wrapper = () => {
  // useFocusEffect from above.

  return <SomeClassComponent />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In react native when you change screen and come back to the previous screen it doesn't rerenders so using useEffect hook doesen't work. However you can use `useFocusEffect` hook provided by the react navigation. You can read more in details [Here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/)

Comment: Thank you. Would you please write more details with your code?